# filter div by select option to match year within paragraph tag

Tags: jquery, regex, show-hide

I am fairly new to get the selection to show hide paragraphs that has matching year.
So if I select 2014, only P tags with 2014 inside them will show. Select all shows all P tags.

```
<form>
<select id="yearFilter">
<option>All</option>
<option>2014</option>
<option>2013</option>
</select>
</form>

<div id="articles">
<p>The year of 2014 A</p>
<p>The year of 2014 B</p>
<p>The year of 2013 A</p>
<p>The year of 2013 B</p>
</div>

The js:

<script>
var a = $("#articles p:contains('0')").push( $(this).text() );

console.log(a);

</script>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Do you want this: `var a = $("#articles p:contains('2014')").text();` ?

Comment: I think my question is what are the steps I need to do in order to create that Select option to show/hide the Paragraph with the corresponding year. do i use regex to grab all the years formats and then match them to Select-options??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` does not refer to any jQuery object in your context.

To show/hide on select value change:

```
<form>
<select id="yearFilter">
<option value="0">All</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
</select>
</form>

<div id="articles">
<p>The year of 2014 A</p>
<p>The year of 2014 B</p>
<p>The year of 2013 A</p>
<p>The year of 2013 B</p>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
$('#yearFilter').change(function () {
    var year = $(this).val();
    $("#articles p").hide();
    $("#articles p:contains('" + year + "')").show();
});
```

To see how well it works: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleKatarn/4grf3d8o/1/